# TypeScript: Import project's module from another project with different tsconfig

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a Cypress setup with its own `tsconfig` *inside* another project with the main `tsconfig`. Cypress works just fine on its own, but now I'm trying to import a module from the main project and getting `resolve` errors, since the Cypress' TS config can't figure out where the module is.

Any idea how I can modify Cypress' tsconfig to allow for that? Here's the config (cleaned up):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": ["cypress", "@percy/cypress", "node"],
  }
}
```

And this is the main project's config (cleaned up):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest", "node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "./jest-setup.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The project's structure is like this:

```
- node_modules
- tsconfig.json (the main project's)
- src
  - components
  - utils 
  - ... etc etc
- e2e
  - tsconfig.json (cypress')
  - node_modules
  - cypress
    - all the code for cypress, tests, etc
```

Error:

[image]

Things I've tried to far:

-- updating the `paths` to be the same as the main projects' (to no avail, same error happens)

```
 "baseUrl": ".",
 "paths": {
   "@/*": ["../../src/*"]
 }
```

Comment: One thing I see unusual about your question is that you seem to have your Cypress tests under a folder called e2e rather than cypress.   We know that Protractor used the e2e folder.  So, this suggests to me you didn't apply the cypress schematic properly.   Right?   You should remove the e2e folder, install cypress folder, then apply schematic.  Also FYI, your types array probably doesn't need "node".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the paths mapping you have in your main config also into your subprojects config. Should probably look something like this, if i get your folder structure right:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": ["cypress", "@percy/cypress", "node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["../src/*"]
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this already with no success. I keep getting the exact same error. Updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: I've got your folder structure wrong, did you already try this ["../src/*"]?. Because ["../../src/*"] is wrong, if the depiction of your folder structure is correct. In a small sample project i've setup with your configs, it did work.

Comment: That worked. Sigh, I was sure I had tried that too, I guess I made the same mistake lol. I'm having a different error now but this is solved. Thanks!